# How do I upload an image to a ServiceStack service?

Tags: file-upload, xamarin.android, servicestack, filestream, image-uploading

I have the path of an image, and use the following code to send it to my server;

```cs
HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://212.175.132.168/service/api/upload/cab.jpg");
client.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post; 

// the following 4 rows enable streaming 
client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
client.SendChunked = true;
client.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
client.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead (filePath)) {
    fileStream.Copy (client.GetRequestStream ());
}

var response = new StreamReader (client.GetResponse ().GetResponseStream ()).ReadToEnd ();
```

But the code doesn't work, image isn't attached. What I am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## HttpWebRequest + `multipart/form-data` needs boundaries:

By using `HttpWebRequest` with `multipart/form-data` requires that you specify the boundaries of your content. Which is rather a lot of work and can easily cause corrupt uploads if you don't understand it. However [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/566462/1295344) covers how to do it.

## Use the PCL ServiceStack.Client:

But as you are using a ServiceStack backend, then the best approach is to use the [ServiceStack.Client PCL library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client.Pcl/) in your Android application, which provides the easy to use `JsonServiceClient`. *[See this example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) for a full Android with ServiceStack demonstration.*

So given a simple Upload Service (on your server side):

```cs
[Route("/upload","POST")]
public class UploadFileRequest
{
    // Example of other properties you can send with the request
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

class MyFileService : Service
{
    public bool Post(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        // Check a file has been attached
        if(Request.Files == null || Request.Files.Length == 0)
            throw new HttpError(400, "Bad Request", "No file has been uploaded");

        // Save the file
        Request.Files[0].SaveTo(Request.Files[0].FileName);

        // Maybe store the tags (or any other data in the request)
        // request.Tags

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then with the `JsonServiceClient` in your Android app, then your simply need to do this:

```cs
var filename = "cab.jpg"; // The path of the file to upload
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://212.175.132.168/service/api/");
using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    client.PostFileWithRequest<bool>(fileStream, "cab.jpg", new UploadFileRequest { Tags = new[] { "Cab", "Taxis", "NewYork", "Yellow" }});
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks its sending but cant find file path, im converting path from after select or capture photo like GetRealPathFromURI or destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, filePath);
when i try to send says me file cant find so cant uploaded plus i voted you as great answer thanks

Comment: ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
DEBUG: Status Code : NotFound
DEBUG: Status Description : Not Found