# When uploading an image/file to server, ServiceStack throws a UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: android, stream, xamarin.android, servicestack, filestream

I used the following code from the answer to this question by @scott [How do I upload an image to a ServiceStack service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886245/how-do-i-upload-an-image-to-a-servicestack-service)

```cs
[Route("/upload","POST")]
public class UploadFileRequest
{
    // Example of other properties you can send with the request
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

class MyFileService : Service
{
    public bool Post(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        // Check a file has been attached
        if(Request.Files == null || Request.Files.Length == 0)
            throw new HttpError(400, "Bad Request", "No file has been uploaded");

        // Save the file
        Request.Files[0].SaveTo(Request.Files[0].FileName);

        // Maybe store the tags (or any other data in the request)
        // request.Tags

        return true;
    }
}
```

> Then with the `JsonServiceClient` in your Android app, then your simply need to do this:

```cs
var filename = "cab.jpg"; // The path of the file to upload
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://212.175.132.168/service/api/");
using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    client.PostFileWithRequest<bool>(fileStream, "cab.jpg", new UploadFileRequest { Tags = new[] { "Cab", "Taxis", "NewYork", "Yellow" }});
}
```

I used this with my DTO and in my Android app, but when I try to send it always fails with the following server error:

```
{"ResponseStatus": {"ErrorCode":"UnauthorizedAccessException","Message":"'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\inetsrv\\a.png' path denied.", 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\a.png' path denied.
```

Can anyone share Monodroid ServiceStack Image upload sample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the example code, [that you have taken from my answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25889619/1295344), which you used in the Monodroid client. It works on Monodroid using the ServiceStack PCL library without modification.

## Monodroid:

No modification required.

```cs
var filename = "cab.jpg"; // The path of the file to upload
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://212.175.132.168/service/api/");
using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    client.PostFileWithRequest<bool>(fileStream, "cab.jpg", new UploadFileRequest { Tags = new[] { "Cab", "Taxis", "NewYork", "Yellow" }});
}
```

## Server File Permissions Error:

The error message you get when you upload to the ServiceStack service shows that your server process does not have permission to write the file to this directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`.

```
{
    "ResponseStatus":     
    {
        "ErrorCode":"UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "Message":"'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\a.png' path denied."
    }
}
```

You need to update the server side service to write the file to a path which the service has permission to.

```cs
class MyFileService : Service
{
    public bool Post(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        // Check a file has been attached
        if(Request.Files == null || Request.Files.Length == 0)
            throw new HttpError(400, "Bad Request", "No file has been uploaded");

        // Replace with a path you have permission to write to
        var path = @"c:\temp\image.png";

        // Save the file
        Request.Files[0].SaveTo(path);

        // Maybe store the tags (or any other data in the request)
        // request.Tags

        return true;
    }
}
```

If you fix the permission error you will see it works.

Comment: allright, currently i can not access to server side, tomorrow i will try it ( write / update auth from windows server ) thanks, i was whole lost my time while try old pcl libraries, i just updated and get this connection info anyway thanks

Comment: why did you -1 my question?

Comment: @HâlukYilmaz I -1 because your question lacked formatting and capitalisation of words. Furthermore the request for specific code examples is off topic and the error was indicated in the error message with `Path denied`. However I have formatted your question for you and removed the downvote.

Comment: ok it worked :) now i will try to load it from temp directory is it easy as upload? and second question is http://212.175.132.168/next/api/json/metadata?op=CityReportsAdd this is my add class, so can i call same time or should i upload twice ? thanks for advice from now